# Android Drag Drop issue on Emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, drag-and-drop

I wrote working code to implement drag and drop in Android, and I fully tested the project on a device (SAMSUNG Galaxy Note) and everything is working fine. However, there is a major issue if I run the project on an emulator: the drag works fine, but the drop functionality is not working: once I drag the view, if I drop over a view that has a onDragListener, nothing happens (as if the view doesn't have a onDragListener). I can also see the following in LogCat (in the Eclipse IDE) every time I try to drag and drop:

> (Tag:) ViewRootImpl , (Text:) Reporting drop result: false.

Is drag and drop not supported on the emulator ? Can I enable it somehow ?

I am using Android 4.0.3 (API 15).

Comment: Hey, I got issue with OnDragListener. I implemented onDragListener for dragging dynamically created view. Now I'm getting "Reporting drop result: false" in logcat. (not in emulator) using HTC ONE X.